# Efficiently get user info for reviews collection query

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a product document and a sub-collection of its reviews. Each review has the userId of the user that created the document. I want to efficiently get all users from those reviews without having to read each document beforehand.

I can query efficiently for those reviews but I can't think of a way to get the user info of the reviews i'm querying without doing a single query for the user after reading the document. Any Ideas?

```
productDocument.collection("reviews")
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

     for reviewDocument in querySnapshot!.documents {
            let review = reviewDocument.data()
            let userId = review.senderId

            usersCollection.document(userId).getDocument { (userDocument, error) in
           if let userDocument = userDocument{
                let user = userDocument.data()
                print("\(user.name) said \(review.text)")
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need all user data? In my case I don't do loads of duplication but I store a map of uid, username and profile picture. Might be worthwhile

Comment: Yes Dan, I guess for a simple review it might not be critical to have the most updated name.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore doesn't have any "join" type queries that can combine results from multiple collections.  In your case, you are going to have to query and iterate each document in reviews, collect all the user IDs from those documents, then fetch each user document individually.  There's no shortcut for this provided by the SDKs, though you might want to write a utility function of your own.

If this is unacceptable, consider adding another collection that you can query once that will give you everything you need.  It is not uncommon to duplicate data in NoSQL type databases in order to optimize situations like this.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I don't consider it unacceptable, I just find it inefficiently. I think that's the only way to go without duplicating data. I'll also analyze the importance of having an updated name for this scenario, as it might not be that  important for a simple review.